# TableView Scrolling on Button Click Qml

Tags: qt, qml, tableview, qt5, qtquick2

Is there any property by which i can scroll up and down on button clicked in tableview. I don't want vertical scroll bar visible but i want to make it scroll on button clicks ?

I don't want to increment currentrow value, i want to make currentrow value fix,
I just want to scroll tableview list on button click.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flick` method to scroll `TableView`. For scrolling down:

```
myTableView.flick(0, -1000)
```

and for scrolling up:

```
myTableView.flick(0, 1000)
```

Here `1000` is the velocity in y direction. You can change it to your desired value.

Comment: Hi @Nejat , In tableview there is no property like flick. As i am using tableview_id.flick, it is showing error.

Comment: `TableView` inherits `Flickable` which has a method named `flick`.

Comment: Hi @Nejat I am getting this error, " TypeError: Property 'flick' of object TableView_QMLTYPE_41(0x4bc1ec60) is not a function"

Comment: Are you sure you are using `TableView` from Qt Quick 2 module?

Comment: Hi @Nejat when i used "import QtQuick 2.12" then it is getting "flick" function, but previously i was using "import QtQuick 2.9", now after importing "import QtQuick 2.12", some of the properties i defined earlier is showing errors like "itemDelegate", "headerVisible", "rowdelegate",etc. what can i do ?

Comment: You should change them to adapt to the new TableView from Qt Quick 2. See the documentation of `TableView`: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.12/qml-qtquick-tableview.html

Comment: Hi @Nejat , Ok i will try that one, But what about singal handler "Onclicked", is it like we can't use in this tableview, previously it was showing no error, now it is showing error !

Comment: @BHUSHANSURE Are you talking about `OnClicked` handlers in your buttons?

Comment: Hi, @Nejat , onclicked() handlers in tableview, like when i click on certain row of table the some action should happen !!

Comment: Hi, @Nejat, i fixed this, Thank you, I want to know one more thing that how to flick by certain height only, by one row height it should flick. Now it is getting flick uptil last element in tableview.

Comment: @BHUSHANSURE I think you can change flick value from `1000` to a lower value to adjust your need.

Comment: Hi, @Nejat I use "contentY" property and my problem is solved now